# Sqoop import mysql to hive ,data uncorrect

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I used sqoop to import some data from mysql to hive and when it finished,I found some columns are incorrect in some rows.
Here is my code:

```
bin/sqoop import -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=mypath  
--table mytable  --hive-overwrite --hive-table myhivetable 
--username myname -–password-alias mydb.password.alias   
--connect  myconn  -m 1 --null-string '**' --null-non-string '**'
--fields-terminated-by '\001'  --lines-terminated-by '\n'
```

Here is the correct data in mysql:

[image: data]

but in hive it is:

[image: hive]

Here are some rows in hive:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be somewhat in this format

Sqoop import - - connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/tablename - - driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver - - table tablename - - hive-import